# Unchecking the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" option does not remove DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016 I have two NICs, one of which has multiple IP addresses (172.x) and the other that has just one (192.x). On the NIC that's 172.x, I've unchecked the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" checkbox in the DNS settings (see picture below). However, when I go to DNS Manager and check the entries for my domain, that server has the IP addresses for both NICs appearing in the list. I would expect the ones for the NIC that has "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" unchecked to not appear there.

I followed the instructions on the MS support page [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/clearing-the-register-this-connection-s-addresses-in-dns-option-does-not-remove-dns-records-for-windows-clients-using-static-ip-addresses-e31e711c-5f21-d647-5bbc-5b5c77e85805)  (restarting the DNS client service, since the server has static IPs) but that didn't work.

Has anyone else come across this issue and know of a working solution?

[unchecked box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBa3s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's registered as a dynamic record, and your DNS admin has enabled auto scavenge, then an idle record will be removed in next scavenging cycle (default 7 days, but I could remember wrong).
Otherwise, a registered (static) record will stay in DNS forever until you manually remove it.
Unchecking the registration option doesn't do anything in DNS database. It only means the client no longer sends update command to DNS server.

Comment: It's a static record, and it was not removed due to the computer is not the owner of the record.